# Calculate Rates with period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, join

I am new in Ruby but I try to make a reservation system !!!

I have a model called "Room" with the name and the price (done) :

```
room 1 | $100
room 2 | $150
room 3 | $200
...
```

I have also a model called "Rate" with name, beginning_period, ending_period and %_price (done)

```
Season1_standard | 08/01/2014 | 09/30/2014 | 100%
OtherSeason1_standard | 08/15/2014 | 10/25/2014 | 70%
Season2_standard | 10/01/2014 | 12/31/2014 | 80%
Season3_standard | 01/01/2015 | 03/31/2015 |90%
...
```

i made a join table (done) :

```
room has_and_belongs_to_many :rates
rate has_and_belongs_to_many :rooms
```

so i can select rates for a room and rooms for a rate.

Now my problem is :

I have a model called "reservation" with room, start_date and end_date, price and i would like to calculate the value price:

for exemple :

I want to book room 1 from 09/28/2014 to 10/04/2014 ( 6 nights )

room1 is linked to season1_standard and season2_standard

so i try to make something like this :

```
09/28/2014 = $100 * 100% = $100
09/29/2014 = $100 * 100% = $100
09/30/2014 = $100 * 100% = $100
10/01/2014 = $100 * 80% = $80
10/02/2014 = $100 * 80% = $80
10/03/2014 = $100 * 80% = $80
```

and my price will be the sum = $540

I'm lost. I don't know where to start ! I suppose i have to do something in my reservation model but i don't know how to get back the value from the join table rates_rooms ?

If you have any idea or link to learn some new concept it will be perfect for me

tks a lot

**EDIT : table and code**

so this is the real code with text in french !

```
create_table "villas", force: true do |t|
t.string   "nom"
t.float    "prix_nuit_hs"

create_table "tarifications", force: true do |t|
t.string   "nom"
t.date     "periode_debut", limit: 255
t.date     "periode_fin",   limit: 255
t.integer  "pct_prix_base"

create_table "reservations", force: true do |t|
t.string   "date_debut"
t.string   "date_fin"
t.integer  "prix_location"
```

So in reservation.rb

```
def calcul
  dd = Date.strptime(date_debut, "%m/%d/%Y")
  df = Date.strptime(date_fin, "%m/%d/%Y")
  prix_location = 0
  [dd..df].each do |date|
    tarification = villa.tarifications.where('periode_debut >= ? AND periode_fin <= ?',date,date).first
    prix_location += tarification.pct_prix_base * villa.prix_nuit_hs
  end
  return prix_location
end
```

I tried to change date_debut et date_fin in date without Date.strptime in the code but I have the same error Thanks a lot for your help

**EDIT**

Sorry, I didn't see all the modifications. So I tried this new code :

```
  def calcul
  dd = Date.strptime(date_debut, "%m/%d/%Y")
  df = Date.strptime(date_fin, "%m/%d/%Y")
  prix_location = 0
  [dd..df].each do |date|
    tarification = Tarification.where('periode_debut >= ? AND periode_fin <= ?',date,date).select{|r| r.in?(villa.tarifications)}.first
    prix_location += tarification.pct_prix_base * villa.prix_nuit_hs
  end
  return prix_location
end
```

But i still have this message error :

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "tarifications".* FROM "tarifications" WHERE (periode_debut >= '2014-09-03','2014-09-04','2014-09-05','2014-09-06' AND periode_fin <= '2014-09-03','2014-09-04','2014-09-05','2014-09-06')
```

Tks

EDIT : SOLUTION

A friend find the solution :

dd.upto(df) for each date !

Tks a lot

Comment: Start by iterating through the dates (e.g., `[start_date..end_date].each do |date|`
Withing the loop retrieve the appropriate rate for the room and add that to the total.

Comment: what is the association between reservation, room & rate.

Comment: reservation - belongs_to :room / rate - has_and_belongs_to_many :rooms / room - has_many :reservation and has_and_belongs_to_many :rates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total_price = 0
[start_date..end_date].each do |date|
  rate = Rate.where('beginning_period >= ? AND ending_period <= ?',date,date).select{|r| r.in?(room.rates)}.first
  total_price += rate.%_price * room.price
end
return total_price
```

Comment: I create a class in my reservertion.rb but I have a SQL error ? :

SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "rates".* FROM "rates" INNER JOIN "rates_rooms" ON "rates"."id" = "rates_rooms"."rate_id" WHERE "rates_rooms"."room_id" = ? AND (beginning_period >= '2014-09-11','2014-09-12','2014-09-13','2014-09-14','2014-09-15','2014-09-16','2014-09-17','2014-09-18' AND ending_period<= '2014-09-11','2014-09-12','2014-09-13','2014-09-14','2014-09-15','2014-09-16','2014-09-17','2014-09-18') ) ORDER BY "rates"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

I have also a stupid question : where I use my %_price ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the above code? The SQL query seems weird, doesn't look like the output of the above. I edited the answer to reflect the %_price, sorry my bad.

Comment: Thanks NicoFerna. However I still have this sql error. I wrote the code above in a class "calcul_price" in my model reservertion.rb . It 's the good place ?

Comment: Yes, it should be the right place, please update your question with your code.